# How to generate performance report in PostgreSQL same as AWR in Oracle?

Tags: postgresql

I need to identify the queries (or related database actions) in PostgreSQL database. 
In Oracle, we have AWR to check all things related to database server. How we generate report in PostgreSQL like Oracle?
I also researched and found [POWA](https://powa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) tool but did not see any guidance to install it in Windows (My PostgreSQL was installed in Azure).
Could you please advise?

Thank you.

Comment: You won't have much luck finding many tools for Postgres on Windows. Linux is the most used platform for Postgres and as such most tool writers concentrate on that.

Comment: There is no tool for PostgreSQL exactly like AWR, but there are tools that can provide you with similar information (maybe you'd have to use multiple tools here). Which information do you care about most? I've found [pghero](https://github.com/ankane/pghero) good for a start but for production you might need much more. If you have an existing monitoring solution you should search for an integration with that. If you're at Azure, I'd recommend using it's PostgreSQL service and you'll get performance monitoring: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-monitoring